# automatic sync of resharper 7 settings / live templates between several computers

Tags: resharper, resharper-7.1

Is it possible to automatically synchronise settings between computers, especially LiveTemplates?

Basically, I would like that if I add a LiveTemplate on a computer, it would be automatically added to all the other development team machines.  Currently, the only option I managed was to export the settings to a file (.DotSettings), and then re-import them on another machine.  However, this is very tedious if you have computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Explicitly move all your settings to solution layer. This would create ".DotSettings" file near your "*.sln" file.
2. Check this ".DotSettings" file into source control.
3. After that, use "Save to" to save your settings changes to this layer (and select this layer in Live Templates Explorer).

Now every change to settings now automatically propagates to all of your team computers via source control. Read more about this at http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/resharper-settings/